# Heat transfer through window

Tags: thermodynamics

I was wondering what is the ideal number of glass layers in a windows assuming outside T2 is greater than inside T1 and we want T1 to remain as low as possible (ie. keep the room cool). Now heat capacity (C) and thermal conductivity (λ) of air between glass layers is lower than that of glass but having no glass is essentially having window open which obviously isn't correct solution. On the other hand stack of glass cannot be ideal as well. So there is some middle ground. Maybe theoretically there should be infinite number of as thin as possible layers of glass separated with air?

Thank you.

Comment: The solution is to have a vacuum between two layers of glass, as vacuum is hard to make,they use inert gases https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulated_glazing

Comment: Sure but there has to be a differrence between having two layers of glass (outside and inside) and 3 layers (one in between). 3 is apparently better but then why not 4, 5, 6?

Comment: Cost effectiveness, air conditioning and heating costs

Comment: What if cost isn't an issue ie. in theory at what point (at how many layers) does higher thermal conductivity of glass vs air (or whatever gass) becomes an issue ?

Comment: ask in engineering

Comment: Triple glazing can be more effective in controlling heat transfer than double glazing.